# uncaught error class magento/indexer/model/config/reader

Tags: magento2, php, setup-di-compile, setup-upgrade

I have been facing this issue since ui upgraded my magento site form 2.0.7 to 2.1.5.
When trying to run magento setup:upgarde command to install extension it gives uncaught error class magento/indexer/model/config/reader in abstractFactory.php

Php version i am currently using is 7.0.17 . I have tried using di:compile also but of no use.

If some one can give a solution it will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: Delete var/generation , cache directories and view_processed , give proper permissions and then try this command again.

Comment: Did the above work?